# Ionic 4 opening modal from within another modal : modal.create() is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to open a modal dialog from within another modal dialog, by searching through the web I can see that people did it before without problems, but I can't seem to get it working.

When I try to create my second modal component from the first modal component it says:

> TypeError: this.modal.create is not a function

Here's my code (trimmed with the relevant parts).

**Component.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    QuizResultComponent,
    AnswerRecapComponent
  ],
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, IonicModule, FontAwesomeModule],
  exports: [
    QuizResultComponent,
    AnswerRecapComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    QuizResultComponent,
    AnswerRecapComponent
  ]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

This is how I open the first modal: 
**Exam.page.ts**

```
... 
export class ExamPage implements OnInit {

    ...

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private modal: ModalController
    ) {}

    ...

    async openModal(){
        // Creating the result modal
        const modal = await this.modal.create({
        component: QuizResultComponent,
        componentProps: {
            type: 'exam'
        }
        });

        // Registering back to menu event after dismiss
        modal.onDidDismiss().then(_ => this.router.navigate(['/menu']));

        // Showing modal
        return await modal.present();
    }

    ...

}
```

And this is for the second modal from **quiz-result.component.ts** where the exception is throw.

```
... 
export class QuizResultComponent implements OnInit {

    ...

    constructor(
    private modal: ModalController,
    private navParams: NavParams
  ) {}

    ...

    async openAnswerRecap(q) {
        const modal = await this.modal.create({ // This line throws the exception.
            component: AnswerRecapComponent,
            componentProps: {
                question: q.question
            }
        });

        return await modal.present();
    }

    ...

}
```

I don't really see any problem with this code, is there something that prevents me from opening a modal from another modal component ?

Comment: Everything looks fine. Did you import the components module into the parent page module that shows both of those modals? e.g. imports: [ComponentModule]

I also deleted the modules belonging to the modal components as it can throw a duplicate import error

Answer (score 12):

In my case, i created on the second modal controller different name on constructor, like:

First Modal: constructor(private modal: ModalController)
Second Modal: constructor(private _modal: ModalController)

And add in your module entryPoint for 2 modals.

Comment: Didn't think of that, will try it when I have time. Thanks !

Comment: This works. Did not even thought about it that way (2 modals with the same name gets added to the DOM)

Answer (score 1):

The thing to remember is a modal in Ionic v4 is just a component, not a page.

The way I got it to work was by importing both modals (declarations, exports and entryComponents) in a shared module and importing that modal within the parent page's module that displays them. Similar to what OP has done.

I also deleted the modules generated by default by the cli (if you did ionic g page sampleModal).

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue , there is a workaround for that .
Let us take u have three to four models windows you have to call on one after other like a  chain .
U must be having ok or next button for each window , on the click method call two events like
Onclick=create ():close
Methods

Answer (score 0):

I have the same case and solved it like this:

You will need to import the `AnswerRecapModule` on the `QuizResultModule`.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    ....

    AnswerRecapModule

  ],
})
export class QuizResultModule { }
```

If you don't have a Module for both of them create it.

Moreover: @Luiz Carlos answer will be needed also, create two ModalController on `QuizResultComponent`

```
export class QuizResultComponent implements OnInit {

    ...

    constructor(
    private QuizModal: ModalController,
    private AnswerModal: ModalController,

    private navParams: NavParams
  ) {}
```

where `QuizModal` for dismissing the current modal, and `AnswerModal` to create `AnswerRecapComponent`